# Trying to execute azure functions in vscode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I have been trying to deploy a flask application with azure function. And it's not working.
I am new to azure...

My flask application is a simple calculator and I want to use azure function online.
My files directory are the following:

```
flaskapp
      |-flask application;
      |-index.html
azure_function:HTTP trigger function
      |-__init__.py
      |-function.json
```

Here is my **init**.py

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:

    return func.WsgiMiddleware(application).handle(req, context)
```

When I try to debug my function locally in vs code, I cannot make it work: 404 not found.
And when I execute the function I get: Executed function "functionName". Response: `"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"> <title>404 Not Found</title> <h1>Not Found</h1> <p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p> "`

Can someone help me please?

Comment: A lot of info is missing. What's the trigger/binding for function? How do you "execute the function"? E.g. on Portal or on laptop on CLI or Postman/curl or... ? Where do you see the response you mentioned? In log file, on UI, on CLI.. ?

Comment: On my side it is no problem. Any logs?

Comment: Where Can I find the logs @BowmanZhu?

Comment: Go to`C:\Users\yourusernameonlocal\AppData\Local\Temp\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Function\yourfunctionname`.

Comment: And the terminal of VSCode should show the logs.

Answer (score -1):

This question needs more details.

404 Not found error always mean you miss some basic things. The default port of flask application on local is different from azure function's on local(azure function is 7071).

And debug azure function doesn't mean only debug `__init__.py`. In fact, it means debug the whole function app(To achieve this, you need to install azure function core tools, azure function plugin of VSCode and language debug plugin).

Comment: I just altered the question, to have more detail